# Is Min Heap Function

Tags: python, heap, min-heap

I want to write a function that tells me whether a given list is a min heap.

What I have written so far:

```
def is_min_heap(L):
    return _is_min_heap(L, 0)

def _is_min_heap(L, i):
    if 
         #base case
    else:
        return (L[i] < L[2*i+1] and _is_min_heap(L, 2*i+1)) and (L[i] < L[2*i+2] and _is_min_heap(L, 2*1+2))
```

I am not sure what the base case should be and is my recursive calls correct?

Also how can you control that the indexes are not eventually out of range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three different cases for a given `i`: Either you have two children, in which case you need to check the heap property for both children and also recursively check both subtrees; or you have just a left children, in which case you just have to check that one; or you have no children, i.e. `i` is a leaf, which is always a valid heap by itself.

You can check the existence of a children by checking if its index is still in range with the list.

```
def _is_min_heap(L, i):
    l, r = 2 * i + 1, 2 * i + 2

    if r < len(L): # has left and right children
        if L[l] < L[i] or L[r] < L[i]: # heap property is violated
            return False

        # check both children trees
        return _is_min_heap(L, l) and _is_min_heap(L, r)
    elif l < len(L): # only has left children
        if L[l] < L[i]: # heap property is violated
            return False

        # check left children tree
        return _is_min_heap(L, l)
    else: # has no children
        return True
```