# Uniqueness of min heap?

Tags: python, heap

**Can we create multiple min heaps from a given unique non-heap list?**

Both `L1` and `L2` below (which share the exact same elements, but not in the same order) are legitimate min heaps of this original non-heap list: `[12,12,3,12,12,12,12,9,6,6,10,4,20]`

`L1=[3,4,9,6,10,12,12,12,6,12,12,12,20]`
`L2=[3,6,4,9,6,12,12,12,12,12,10,12,20]`

This seems weird to me. Is it common knowledge? I would love to get some confirmation on that.

**Appendix**:
This Python [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864434/is-min-heap-function) checks whether a list verifies the min heap conditions: `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]` and `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2]` for all k's:

```
def is_min_heap(L):
    return _is_min_heap(L, 0)

def _is_min_heap(L, i):
    l, r = 2 * i + 1, 2 * i + 2

    if r < len(L): # has left and right children
        if L[l] < L[i] or L[r] < L[i]: # heap property is violated
            return False

        # check both children trees
        return _is_min_heap(L, l) and _is_min_heap(L, r)
    elif l < len(L): # only has left children
        if L[l] < L[i]: # heap property is violated
            return False

        # check left children tree
        return _is_min_heap(L, l)
    else: # has no children
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

> May I point you to this related problem of the [max heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552777/when-building-heap-is-heap-unique)?

I think that in short, the second answer to that question covers it all: *the heap constraint (which is that children are greater than their parents) does not completely specify the heap, so there is usually more than one possible arrangement.* For the min heap, the same constraint applies, so again, there could be more than one possible arrangement and hence uniqueness cannot be guaranteed.